# NODE_ENV was unexpected at this time error

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I am following this tutorial on youtube because i am trying to learn node.js / express.

I changed the following in my package.json file to be able to use nodemon.

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "if [[ $NODE_ENV == 'production' ]]; then node ./bin/www; else nodemon ./bin/www; fi"
  },
```

However when i run the following command in my cmd prompt I get an error.

```
set DEBUG=myapp:* & npm start
```

**Error below:**

```
$NODE_ENV was unexpected at this time.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myapp@0.0.0 start: `if [[ $NODE_ENV == 'production' ]]; then node ./bin/www; else nodemon ./bin/www; fi`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myapp@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

- I've already tried updating all npm modules.
  -I'ved tried deleting package-lock.json and reinstalling everything.

I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Your shell needs to be able to interpret that syntax. It's not an installation issue, its a shell syntax error. Like if I were on Ubuntu and tried to use `rmdir /S /Q www`, it would fail

Comment: I have the same issue. I don't have answer but seems that if a variable is not defined that the script stops instead of proceeding with the `else` part.

Answer (score 1):

I tried installing nodemon globally and it worked.

> `npm install -g nodemon`

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node ./bin/www"
}
```

and used `nodemon` to start the app

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error but I changed it to :

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "node ./bin/www",
   "dev": "nodemon ./bin/www"
 },
```

it works for me I'm using "yarn dev" and "npm run dev" for npm.

Answer (score 0):

"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  }

now run nodemon or npm start

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just run nodemon You can do it simply like this

```
"start" : "nodemon ./bin/www"
```

and that's all. you're all clear to go